# Trouble with DFS in solving coastline length

Tags: c++, depth-first-search

I'm trying to solve one problem, which I found on website https://open.kattis.com/problems/coast. Tl;dr version of problem is, that for given map of landscape, I should print out length of coastline (without inner islands).

My idea was, to solve this by adding additional layer and then start DFS, so the algorithm will walk through every possible tile in map, and then watch on every tile, how many borders are around the tile.

However, for specific input, is my algorithm not working. When I've submitted the solution on this site (open.kattis), it says, that my program is giving wrong answer in 9th of 26 tests (previous 8 test were ok), but without any further explanation.

Can somebody look at my program, and say me, why is it bad? Where did I do mistake? Thanks

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string line;
    getline(cin, line);

    int rows = 0;
    int columns = 0;

    stringstream stream(line);
    stream >> rows;
    stream >> columns;

    int map[rows][columns];

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        getline(cin, line);
        for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
            map[i][j] = line[j] - 48;
        }
    }
    //parsed landscape into 2d array

//    int rows = 5;
//    int columns = 6;
//    int map[rows][columns] = {
//            {0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0,},
//            {0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0,},
//            {1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0,},
//            {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0,},
//            {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,},
//    };

int bigMap[rows+2][columns+2];
bool visited[rows+2][columns+2];

//create bigger map, so DFS can start from corner and assume
//that there is water around everywhere
//also initialize array visited for DFS

//add 2 new rows, before and after existing one
for (int i = 0; i < columns+2; i++) {
    bigMap[0][i] = 0;
    bigMap[rows + 1][i] = 0;

    visited[0][i] = false;
    visited[rows + 1][i] = false;
}

//add 2 new columns, before and after existing
//copy original map to new one
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    bigMap[i+1][0] = 0;
    bigMap[i+1][columns + 1] = 0;

    visited[i+1][0] = false;
    visited[i+1][columns + 1] = false;
    for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
        bigMap[i+1][j+1] = map[i][j];

        visited[i+1][j+1] = false;
    }
}
rows += 2;
columns += 2;

//starting DFS
int x = 0, y = 0;
//visited[x][y] = true; <-- edit
pair <int, int> coordinates;

coordinates.first = x;
coordinates.second = y;

stack<pair <int, int> > st;

//first vertex in stack
st.push(coordinates);

//total sum of borders
int borders = 0;

while(!st.empty()) {
    //check coordinates in each round
    x = st.top().first;
    y = st.top().second;

    //navigate to new vertex (only if new vertex wasn't visited (visited[x][y] == 0) and only
    //if there is water (bigMap[x][y] == 0) and check if new vertex is still in the map
    //if there is no possible vertex, then we reached the end so then pop the vertex and
    //look in another way
    if (visited[x][y+1] == 0 && bigMap[x][y+1] == 0 && y + 1 < columns) {
        y++;
        coordinates.second = y;
        st.push(coordinates);
    } else {
        if (visited[x+1][y] == 0 && bigMap[x+1][y] == 0 && x + 1 < rows) {
            x++;
            coordinates.first = x;
            st.push(coordinates);
        } else {
            if (visited[x][y-1] == 0 && bigMap[x][y-1] == 0 && y > 0) {
                y--;
                coordinates.second = y;
                st.push(coordinates);
            } else {
                if (visited[x-1][y] == 0 && bigMap[x-1][y] == 0 && x > 0) {
                    x--;
                    coordinates.first = x;
                    st.push(coordinates);
                } else {
                    st.pop();
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    //visited new vertex, so look around him and count borders
    visited[x][y] = true;
    if (bigMap[x][y+1] == 1 && y + 1 < columns) borders++;
    if (bigMap[x+1][y] == 1 && x + 1< rows) borders++;
    if (bigMap[x][y-1] == 1 && y > 0) borders++;
    if (bigMap[x-1][y] == 1 && x > 0) borders++;
}
cout << borders << endl;

return 0;
```

Comment: variable length arrays are not standard c++. It is possible their test uses a compiler that gives a warning, and then doesn't allocate memory for the array, leading to undefined behaviour. Can you try it without using variable length arrays (i.e. just set all three of your arrays `map`, `bigmap` and `visited` to something like 1024x1024 - you don't need to change anything but the declarations)

Comment: i don't think, that this is issue, because 9 out of 26 test pass. so, if there will be problem with compiler, it would failed in first test, not in 9th, or like after 1 bugfix in 11th.

there is also time and memory limit, so if i just work with 1024^2 array, i am worrying that alg. won't make it through limits. but thank for your idea :)

Comment: Time limit won't be affected by the size of the arrays as you will still only be accessing the same number of array entries, the rest will be unused. Memory limit is 1024MB which gives you enough for 250 arrays of 1024x1024 32 bit integers. So 3 should not be a problem.

Comment: Ah - actually 1024 will be a problem - you are making your arrays on the stack, which is unlikely to allow such large arrays. It is possible variable length arrays don't use stack in the same way, so it might not be the problem. But if their bigger tests are 1000x1000 it could be an issue. Consider making them `static`, or at least trying a 1000x1000 map on your computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you are reusing the variable `coordinates` each time around the loop without setting it to the correct value. Your `if` test cascade is assuming that `coordinates` is set to the current location. This is only true while you are descending in your dfs. Once you start ascending again, the `coordinate` will be pointing to the wrong place.

Simple solution, add

```
    coordinates = st.top();
```

at the top of your loop.

Here is a sample map that it will currently get wrong.

```
5 6
000000
011100
001010
000100
000000
```

Answer should be 14, but currently you get 18 as the program reaches the lake at row 3, column 4.

To check that it is doing this, add a debugging line at the end of your loop, where it is adding the borders.

```
cout << "adding " << x << " " << y << "\n";
```

You can then verify if the program is considering any locations it shouldn't.

Comment: yes. this was the solution for my problem. thank you very much. i was updating `x = st.top().first; y = st.top().second;` each loop and totally forgot to update `coordinates` variable (so in moving step of DFS, actually one bad coordinate was taken), and in cases with corners like you posted it failed. thank you. 26/26 test passed

Answer (score 0):

I think it will fail for {1,0,0,0},{0,1,1,0},{0,1,1,0},{0,0,0,0}. This is because the walk through is prevented from completing due to setting visited=true for vertex 0,0. Set it false for 0,0 instead should improve things. Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks, this was good point :). I edited the code, and it is working now for the mentioned 9th, and also 10th test, but it is failing for 11th and more. so there are still some bugs. but thank you.